# Selenium - Проблема с поиском элемента на странице

Tags: python, selenium

*Добрый день,*

Пишу бота для инстаграма (масслайкинг, можете загуглить). Использую Selenium в первый раз.  Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
После перехода на пост, боту необходимо **нажать на кнопку**  "ещё "*(см. прикрепленный файл)*. Я не могу найти button. У кнопки нет четких атрибутов, например постоянного класса. XPath - пытался:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[2]/div/div[2]/button')
```

Не находит. Подскажите, как можно найти элемент.

*Заранее спасибо!*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я вообще-то не пользуюсь Instagram, но зарегистрировался. Когда я кликаю на фотографию, всё выглядит почти как на Вашем скриншоте. Вот только вместо `нравится ... и ещё ...` у меня кликабельный текст `19 отметок "Нравится"`. По клику появляется список тех, кому нравится. Почему у Вас иначе?

Comment: Сергей, я говорю про автоматизирования с помощью Selenium

Comment: Это понятно. Непонятно, почему мне Инстаграм выводит другой интерфейс в отношении списка тех, кому нравится. Может дело в том, что я в Канаде - хотя, конечно, странно иметь GEO-зависимые интерфейсы.

Comment: Скорее всего дело в том, что никто из тех, на кого вы подписаны не лайкал этот пост

Comment: Нет, я специально подписался на этого `_doodywoody_` и открываю точно ту же картинку, что и у Вас. Написано: `8 224 отметок нравится`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте конструкцию вида:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'ещё')]")
```